# Python Scikit - Learn: Cross Validation with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Hi I want to use one of the scikit learn's functions for cross validation. What I want is that the splitting of the folds is determined by one of the indexes. For example lets say I have this data with "month" and "day" being the indexes:

```
Month    Day   Feature_1 
January   1      10
          2      20
February  1      30 
          2      40 
March     1      50 
          2      60 
          3      70 
April     1      80 
          2      90
```

Lets say I want to have a 1/4 of the data as test set for each validation. I want this fold seperation to be done by the first index which is the month. In this case the test set will be one of the months and the remaining 3 months will be the training set. As an example one of the train and test split will look like this:

```
TEST SET:
Month    Day   Feature_1 
January   1      10
          2      20

TRAINING SET:
Month    Day   Feature_1 
February  1      30 
          2      40 
March     1      50 
          2      60 
          3      70 
April     1      80 
          2      90
```

How can I do this. Thank you.

Comment: What happens to the `day` index after splitting? Do you use it as a feature in your data or discard it since its an index?

Comment: Yes I will use it as a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called splitting by a group. Check out the [user-guide in scikit-learn here to understand more about it](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators-for-grouped-data):

> ...
>
> To measure this, we need to ensure that all the samples in the
> validation fold come from groups that are not represented at all in
> the paired training fold.
>
> ...

You can use the [`GroupKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#group-k-fold) or other strategies that have Group in the name. A sample can be

```
# I am not sure about this exact command, 
# but after this, you should have individual columns for each index
df = df.reset_index()  

print(df)
Month     Day    Feature_1
January    1           10
January    2           20
February   1           30
February   2           40
March      1           50
March      2           60
March      3           70

groups = df['Month']

from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold

gkf = GroupKFold(n_splits=3)
for train, test in gkf.split(X, y, groups=groups):
    # Here "train", "test" are indices of location, 
    # you need to use "iloc" to get actual values
    print("%s %s" % (train, test))  

    print(df.iloc[train, :])
    print(df.iloc[test, :])
```

**Update**: For passing this into cross-validation methods, just pass the months data to `groups` param in those. Like below:

```
gkf = GroupKFold(n_splits=3)
y_pred = cross_val_predict(estimator, X_train, y_train, cv=gkf, groups=df['Month'])
```

Comment: Hi is there a way of doing this by giving the appropriate input to cv parameter of cross_val_predict function. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
indices = df.index.levels[0]

train_indices = np.random.choice(indices,size=int(len(indices)*0.75), replace=False)
test_indices = np.setdiff1d(indices, train_indices)

train = df[np.in1d(df.index.get_level_values(0), train_indices)]
test = df[np.in1d(df.index.get_level_values(0), test_indices)]
```

**Output**

*Train*

```
              Feature_1
Month    Day           
January  1           10
         2           20
February 1           30
         2           40
March    1           50
         2           60
         3           70
```

*Test*

```
           Feature_1
Month Day           
April 1           80
      2           90
```

**Explanation**

`indices = df.index.levels[0]` takes all the unique from `level=0` index - `Index(['April', 'February', 'January', 'March'], dtype='object', name='Month')`

`train_indices = np.random.choice(indices,size=int(len(indices)*0.75), replace=False)` samples 75% of the indices chosen in previous step

Next we obtain the remaining indices to be `test_indices`

Finally we split train and test accordingly

Comment: Lets say I want to use cross_val_predict module, how can I do this in that context ?

Comment: @s900n doesn't make a diff, you can use `y_pred = cross_val_predict(estimator, X_train, y_train, cv=3)` once you split the `df_train` into `X_train` and `y_train` and same for corresponding test sets

Comment: In this way it will again do a cv with the data I provided as X_train I thing there must be an input like " cv=something" that does the cross validation in the form above but I couldnt find it=)